# Adding and remove from favorites isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Critics and Movies on my app and I am adding the function for crtics to add movies to their favorites. Neither add nor remove is working right now. When trying to add, it's trying to issue a patch request rather than a post. When trying to remove, it's not able to use the delete method, because I don't think it's finding the object to delete. Not sure why this is happening. I'll add all code and some server logs below. Really need some help going over this.

Views:

```
<%= form_for(current_critic.favorites.create, remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :movie_id, @movie.id %>
<%= f.submit "Favorite" %>
<% end %>
```

other

```
<%= form_for(current_critic.favorites.find_by(movie_id: @movie.id), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Un-Favorite" %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

def create
    movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    current_critic.favorite(movie)
    redirect_to current_critic
end

def destroy
    movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    current_critic.un_favorite(movie)
    redirect_to current_critic
end

end
```

applicable code from the critic model

```
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :movies, through: :favorites

def favorite(movie)
    favorites.create(movie_id: movie.id)
end

def un_favorite(movie)
    favorites.find_by(movie_id: movie.id).destroy
end
```

applicable code from the movie model

```
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
has_many :critics, through: :favorites
```

favorite model

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :critic
belongs_to :movie
end
```

Applicable routes

```
resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Server logs when trying to add to favorites

```
Started PATCH "/favorites/28" for 99.39.164.184 at 2015-12-01 02:42:17 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/favorites/28"):
```

Server logs when trying to un-favorite

```
Started DELETE "/favorites/27" for 99.39.164.184 at 2015-12-01 03:18:24   +0000
Processing by FavoritesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Un-Favorite", "id"=>"27"}
  Movie Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 27]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=27):
  app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb:10:in `destroy'
```

Thanks in advance. If any other code will be helpful let me know.

UPDATE: I just tested both the favorite and un_favorite methods in the console, and they both work; however something odd is happening where the id's don't seem to be incrementing by one but instead by a seemingly random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first RoutingError occurs because you use `current_critic.favorites.create` in your view, which returns a record already had an id, so the `form_for` will resolve it to `update` rather than `create`.

=> Solution: replace with `current_critic.favorites.new`

2. The second RecordNotFound occurs because you pass an id of `Favorite` but used to find a `Movie`

=> Solution:

```
def destroy
  favorite = current_critic.favorites.find(params[:id])
  favorite.destroy
  redirect_to current_critic
end
```

Comment: This worked thanks! If you don't mind, could you clarify why those work? I'm confused as to why create returns a record that already exists, could you explain why it does that and why new doesn't? And for the second solution it appears that now it destroys the favorite in the controller, so is the un_favorite method in the model unnecessary?

Comment: @CaedBudris: the `id` will be generated when a record persisted to database. If you looked into the api doc for active_record http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class and http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class:  `new` only instantiates record, and `create` persists it.

Comment: The second one, `current_critic.favorites.find_by(movie_id: @movie.id)` IS a `Favorite` object, so the form_for will return the id of the Favorite object. You can't use a `Favorite`'s id to query a `Movie` record, right?